# MSTest Test Method to check for collection

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mstest, rhino-mocks

I am trying to write a test method to check if the List is being obtained properly.I am very new to MSTest and Rhino Mocks.Till now I have written the below code.

```
   var mockRepository = new MockRepository();
   var menuRepository = mockRepository.DynamicMock<IMenuManager>();
   var expected = new List<Menu>();

  //Need to set expected value  

   var actual = menuRepository.GetMenus();
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

IMenuManager is as below

```
 public interface IMenuManager
 {
       List<Menu> GetMenus();
 }
```

Test method itself:

```
var myMenuList = new List<Menu>(); var menuManagerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMenuManager>(); 
menuManagerMock.Stub(c => c.GetMenus()).Return(myMenuList); 
actual = menuManagerMock.GetMenus();
```

How can I set the expected value in this scenario. Please suggest.GetMenus() reads an XML file and builds a collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myMenuList = new List<Menu>();
// setup the list from XML
var menuManagerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMenuManager>();
menuManagerMock.Stub(c => c.GetMenus()).Return(myMenuList);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the Assert.Inconclusive?